# Edit navigation.js to enable sticky nav bar?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, navigation, sticky

I'm trying to edit the navigation.js of a Wordpress theme so that the sticky-nav shows up on all pages, rather than just article ones.

I know this function is the one to change, removing checking window widths and single/page checks. But I'm unfamiliar with js and unsure how to change this without breaking the site.

```
  Navigation.prototype.stickyNavResizeCallback = function() {
if (
  this.windowwidth() <= 768 ||
  ( Largo.sticky_nav_options.main_nav_hide_article && ($('body').hasClass('single') || $('body').hasClass('page')) )
) {
  this.stickyNavEl.addClass('show');
  this.stickyNavEl.parent().css('height', this.stickyNavEl.outerHeight());
} else if (
  Largo.sticky_nav_options.sticky_nav_display
) {
  this.stickyNavScrollTopHide();
  this.stickyNavEl.parent().css('height', '');
} else {
  this.stickyNavScrollTopHide();
  this.stickyNavEl.parent().css('height', '');
}
this.stickyNavSetOffset();
this.stickyNavTransitionDone();
```

};

Comment: Is the Wordpress theme public? I would like to try it out in a dev environment.

Comment: yep! https://github.com/INN/largo

Comment: @TomDickson not sure if you saw this

Comment: Yep, got it. Looking into it at the moment